# Python: unwanted assignment

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes and two lists of dataframes. I want to make a dataframe element "nan" via the list, but the counterpart is also overwritten. How can I modify only the first one?

```
d
Out[302]: {'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [4, 5, 6]}

dftemp1 = pd.DataFrame(d)

dftemp2 = dftemp1

dftemp_l = [dftemp1, dftemp2]

dftemp_m = dftemp_l.copy()

dftemp_l[0][:] = np.nan
```

The following is what I don't want. I want it not to change.

```
dftemp_m[0]
Out[308]: 
   col1  col2
0   NaN   NaN
1   NaN   NaN
2   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: You have *one* dataframe. `dftemp2 = dftemp1` doesn't make another.

Comment: Nothing you do with the lists makes another dataframe either. Every dataframe operation in this code is operating on the same dataframe.

Comment: You **definitly** want to [read this article](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) to understand why your code doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

may be you need deepcopy,

```py
from copy import deepcopy
dftemp_m = deepcopy(dftemp_l)
```

[copy from DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html)

Comment: That only solves part of the problem. It doesn't fix all the other non-copies going on in the code, like `dftemp2 = dftemp1`.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean,  but I dont think that’s   the point of this question

Answer (score 0):

I think it would help a bit to know what you are trying to achieve. But as others have pointed out, you aren't making copies of anything. In most of those operations you are working from the same original dataframe, with multiple references to it.

Also, don't use 'l' and '1' for similar variable names! I've used dftemp_L and dftemp_M below.

Just taking a guess at what you're hoping to achieve, below is probably the right way to do it.

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [4, 5, 6]}

dftemp1 = pd.DataFrame(d)

dftemp2 = dftemp1.copy()

dftemp_L = [dftemp1, dftemp2]


# There are more pythonic ways to do this, but this explicitly shows what is happening:
dftemp_M = []
for my_df in dftemp_L:
    dftemp_M.append(my_df.copy())

dftemp_M[0][:] = np.nan
```